# Flutter: Cupertino ListTile ? (or How To Create iOS-Like-Settings Menu)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-cupertino

Do we have an easy way of doing that kind of menu below using `CupertinoApp` only ?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, so we can use a `Scaffold` inside a `CupertinoPageScaffold` like that and still use the material `ListTile` which look the same as Cupertino ones.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
        middle: Text('My List'),
      ),
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: _listView(context),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need the entire `Scaffold`, you can just wrap it in Material

Comment: @ThinkDigital good point, `Material` is indeed enough for that purpose. In my case, I am using `ExpansionTile`, but if you want to make an iOS app that really look any native counterparts, the ripple is a dead giveaway that's for sure. The tap feedback ought to be different. How would you suggest to go about it ? Thanks !

Comment: @mackovich You can change the ripple color to transparent so you don't see it.

Comment: My opinion is that Material ListTile breaks Apple's touch effects with ripple. It is not same effect like iOS users like to see. That is reason why I dont like to use ListTile for cupertino widgets. Other problem is problem with theme, light/dark.

Comment: @NikolaJovic I agree.  So what tactic did you use to solve for the best iOS experience using Flutter?

Answer (score 5):

[Flutter 3.7](https://medium.com/flutter/whats-new-in-flutter-3-7-38cbea71133c) added two new widgets: [`CupertinoListSection`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoListSection-class.html) and [`CupertinoListTile`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoListTile-class.html) for showing a scrollable list of widgets in the iOS style.

[image: reminders]
[image: notes]

PR: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/78732

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve results very close to the iOS list by using CupertinoButton instead of ListTile, it's a really flexible component. It also apparently has no ripple effect.

Result:

[image: Result]

*The only drawback to this approach is that the button uses pressedOpacity, but reducing the default value from 0.4 to 0.65 or something like that will work just fine.*

```
CupertinoButton(
  pressedOpacity: 0.65,
  color: Colors.white,
  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
    Radius.circular(0),
  ),
  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 16),
  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Row(
        children: [
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 28,
              width: 28,
              child: DecoratedBox(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.teal,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(4),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.ac_unit_sharp,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            'Snowflake item',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      const Icon(
        Icons.chevron_right,
        color: Colors.grey,
      ),
    ],
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this at pub.dev:

> `cupertino_list_tile: ^0.2.0`
>
> https://pub.dev/packages/cupertino_list_tile